# How Can I Upgrade Ubuntu 10:04 to Xubuntu 12.04.1

Tags: 10.04, xubuntu

According to recent documentation, I'll be given the option next time I login .. to upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04.1. But that's not really what I want.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If this is a command line system you can `sudo do-release-upgrade` and then just `sudo tasksel` and select **xubuntu-desktop** or `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`

If this is a full ubuntu-desktop machine, I would `sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop` && `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` && `sudo apt-get autoremove`, and **then do the upgrade.**

Comment: I guess you first need to install Tasksel for that.

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop` wont remove the packages that came with, you need a way longer command for that.

Comment: The package tasksel should be installed on a default lucid system.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is **yes**, but **don't**. You can do the normal updgrade to 12.04 and then install the `xubuntu-desktop`. But a fresh install of 12.04 if Xubuntu is less risk of any error.

But if you really want to upgrade here's what you need to do:
open a terminal and type:

1. `gedit /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`

Now you need to edit all entries like this `Prompt=lts`

then just do a normal upgrade.

2. `do-release-upgrade`
   Now when this is done just install the xubuntu-desktop. Remember to select the desktop at the log-in screen.
3. `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`

But I recommend to just make a fresh install.

I got my information from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04). It's a great source.